# CreateJS (canvas) Iframe

Tags: javascript

Есть например iframe рекламного блока:

```
<iframe data-aa='1058853' src='//ad.a-ads.com/1058853?size=468x60' scrolling='no' style='width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

Собственно вопрос, как вставить iframe используя createJS?

Код всей функции где хочу внедрить:

```
var _oBg;
var _oMsgText;
var _oContainer;

this._init = function(){
    _oContainer = new createjs.Container();
    s_oStage.addChild(_oContainer);

    // Простенький спрайт на фон (роли никак не играет, использует собственный метод createBitmap)
    var oSprite = s_oSpriteLibrary.getSprite('msg_box');
    _oBg = createBitmap(oSprite);
    _oBg.x = CANVAS_WIDTH/2;
    _oBg.y = CANVAS_HEIGHT/2;
    _oBg.regX = oSprite.width/2;
    _oBg.regY = oSprite.height/2;
    _oContainer.addChild(_oBg);

    // Текст на этом фоне
    _oMsgText = new createjs.Text('Произвольный текст',"46px "+PRIMARY_FONT, "#ffffff");
    _oMsgText.x = CANVAS_WIDTH/2;
    _oMsgText.y = 270;
    _oMsgText.textAlign = "center";
    _oContainer.addChild(_oMsgText);

    // Здесь я пытался вставить фрейм с рекламой
}
```

Моя попытка:

```
    var oAds = document.createElement('iframe');
    oAds.setAttribute('data-aa', '1058853');
    oAds.setAttribute('src', '//ad.a-ads.com/1058853?size=468x60');
    oAds.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
    oAds.setAttribute('style', 'width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden');
    oAds.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
    // Пробовал и new createjs.DOMElement(oAds) и многое другое
    var ads = new createjs.Bitmap(oAds);
    _oContainer.addChild(ads);
```

Попытка без контейнера (что очень ужасно, так как желательно в контейнере), рекламный блок появляется, на за canvas (на заднем плане и не видно):

```
var oAds = document.createElement('iframe');
oAds.setAttribute('data-aa', '1058852');
oAds.setAttribute('src', 'https://ad.a-ads.com/1058852%3Fsize=468x60');
oAds.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
oAds.setAttribute('style', 'width:468px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden');
oAds.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
document.body.appendChild(oAds);
```

p.s. Мучаюсь второй день и ничего не выходит...

Comment: Может это вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514081/how-to-put-iframe-in-to-canvas

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, там вставляют его за пределами canvas...

Comment: что значит _вставить в canvas средствами createJS?_

Comment: @ThisMan, возможно не правильно сформулирован вопрос, попробую по другому... "Как вставить iframe используя createJS?"

Comment: Вы хотите нарисовать в элементе canvas содержимое iframe, или просто расположить элемент iframe строго над canvas'ом?

Comment: @Ainar-G, а что будет более практичнее? Скорее всего расположить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нарисовать содержимое iframe'а на canvas'е не получится, не говоря уже о том, что это скорее всего не то, что вам нужно (реклама?). iframe можно расположить над холстом вот так:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik";

// Тут ваши значения.
iframe.style.height = "240px";
iframe.style.width = "640px";
iframe.style.borderWidth = "0px";

iframe.style.position = "relative";
iframe.style.top = "-240px";

canvas.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, canvas.nextSibling);
```

Пример на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eoLbxncj/.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, пойду экспериментировать!